# How to save fastify swagger api description to local file

Tags: node.js, api, swagger, swagger-ui, fastify

Hi is there is any possibility to save API swagger YAML to local file when starting the project? I'm using fastify-swagger plugin

using exposeRoute enable true and call '/documentation/yaml' API allowed to download YAML via the browser but i need to generate and save this YAML file to local inside the project when initially start the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
// .. your code
fastify.register(require('fastify-swagger'), { ... })
await fastify.listen(8080)

// after the ready or listen call
const yaml = fastify.swagger({ yaml: true })
require('fs').writeFileSync('./swagger.yml', yaml)
```

Comment: This seems non-deterministic. When running this script a few times, it generates different yaml output.

Comment: It is not - just updated dependancies or new routes added imho